# Can one polygon be transformed into another using only parallel translation and proportional scaling?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

At the entrance, two polygons are given (the coordinates of the vertices of these polygons are listed in the order of their traversal; however, the traversal order for different polygon angles can be chosen different). Can one polygon be transformed into another using only parallel translation and proportional scaling?

I have following idea
So,  find some common peak for two polygons and make the transfer of one polygon so that these vertices lie on one point then Scaling so that the neighboring point matches the corresponding point of another polygon, but I think it's wrong , at least I can't write it in code

Is there some special formula or theorem for this problem?

Comment: How would you transform a triangle in a rectange with only linear transformations?

Comment: It's trivial case. Need to consider a more difficult case

Comment: What exactly do you mean by proportional scaling? To scale the `x` or `y` dimension of all points of one of the polygons at once?

Comment: I mean following thing. For example, given 2 polygons(dimension of this polygon is same) and I need to check Is there any sequence of parallel translation or scaling   to transform one polygon to another.

Comment: "the traversal order for different polygon angles can be chosen different" sounds enigmatic.

Comment: Are the matches exact or approximate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the axis-aligned bounding boxes of the two polygons.

If the aspect ratios do not match, the answer is negative. Otherwise the ratio of corresponding sides is your scaling factor. The translation is obtained by linking the top left corners and the transformation equations are

```
X = s.(x - xtl) + Xtl
Y = s.(y - ytl) + Ytl
```

where `s` is the scaling factor and `(xtl, ytl)`, `(Xtl, Ytl)` are the corners.

Now choose a vertex of the first polygon, predict the coordinates in the other and find the matching vertex. If you can't, the answer is negative. Otherwise, you can compare the remaining vertices*.

[image]

---

*I assume that the polygons do not have overlapping vertices. If they can have arbitrary self-overlaps, I guess that you have to try matching all vertices, with all cyclic permutations.

Comment: If the scaling can be negative, one would need to consider alternate correspondences for the corners.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this.

1. Find the necessary parallel transport.
2. Find the necessary scaling.
3. See if they are the same polygon now.

So to start take the vertex that it farthest to the left, and if there is a tie, the one that is farthest down.  Find that for both polygons.  Use parallel transport to put that vertex at the origin for both.

Now take the vertex that is farthest to the right, and if there is a tie, the one that is farthest up.  Find that for both polygons.  If it is not at the same slope, then they are different.  If it is, then scale one so that the points match.

Now see if all of the points match.  If not, they are different.  Otherwise the answer is yes.

Comment: Beware that if the coordinates are noisy, the criterion "farthest to the right" is unreliable near ties.